# json object sort from id angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to sort and display data using angular js. i added sort option to my table. but its not sorting

please check my json data

```
 [
   {
      "id":143,
      "companyName":"XC",
      "dividendIncome":66666666,
      "warrantNo":"777777",
      "taxExempt":0,
      "status":"ACTIVE",
      "periodId":{
         "periodId":4,
         "period":"2020-2021",
         "startDate":"2020-04-01",
         "endDate":"2021-03-31",
         "status":null
      },
      "userId":2,
      "isSpecialCategory":false,
      "isDivDistributByInvestee":false,
      "isDivPaidOutExemptProfits":false,
      "dividendIncomeReceivedDate":"2020-05-12"
   },
   {
      "id":145,
      "companyName":"ghhh",
      "dividendIncome":6700000,
      "warrantNo":"555634",
      "taxExempt":0,
      "status":"ACTIVE",
      "periodId":{
         "periodId":4,
         "period":"2020-2021",
         "startDate":"2020-04-01",
         "endDate":"2021-03-31",
         "status":null
      },
      "userId":2,
      "isSpecialCategory":false,
      "isDivDistributByInvestee":false,
      "isDivPaidOutExemptProfits":false,
      "dividendIncomeReceivedDate":"2020-05-11"
   }
]
```

i am trying to display these data using HTML table. all data displayed properly. i will show the 'ng-repeat' part for your reference

```
  <tr ng-repeat="dividendIncome in dividendIncomeList | orderBy:'-id'">
                                <td>{{dividendIncome.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{dividendIncome.companyName}}</td>
                                <td>{{dividendIncome.warrantNo}}</td>
                                <td align="right">{{dividendIncome.dividendIncome | number:2}}</td>
                                <td align="right">{{dividendIncome.taxExempt| number:2}}</td>
</tr>
```

according to my requirement, i need  to display,
id:145 as a first record and id:143 is the second record

have any issues in my code. can u help to fix this issue

Comment: Hmm looks right to me. Can you produce an example in a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code, its correct and working for me.

Here's is the working example of your code

```js
function LoginController($scope) {

    $scope.dividendIncomeList = [
   {
      "id":143,
      "companyName":"XC",
      "dividendIncome":66666666,
      "warrantNo":"777777",
      "taxExempt":0,
      "status":"ACTIVE",
      "periodId":{
         "periodId":4,
         "period":"2020-2021",
         "startDate":"2020-04-01",
         "endDate":"2021-03-31",
         "status":null
      },
      "userId":2,
      "isSpecialCategory":false,
      "isDivDistributByInvestee":false,
      "isDivPaidOutExemptProfits":false,
      "dividendIncomeReceivedDate":"2020-05-12"
   },
   {
      "id":145,
      "companyName":"ghhh",
      "dividendIncome":6700000,
      "warrantNo":"555634",
      "taxExempt":0,
      "status":"ACTIVE",
      "periodId":{
         "periodId":4,
         "period":"2020-2021",
         "startDate":"2020-04-01",
         "endDate":"2021-03-31",
         "status":null
      },
      "userId":2,
      "isSpecialCategory":false,
      "isDivDistributByInvestee":false,
      "isDivPaidOutExemptProfits":false,
      "dividendIncomeReceivedDate":"2020-05-11"
   }
];
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="dividendIncome in dividendIncomeList | orderBy:'-id'">
       <td>{{dividendIncome.id}}</td>
       <td>{{dividendIncome.companyName}}</td>
       <td>{{dividendIncome.warrantNo}}</td>
       <td align="right">{{dividendIncome.dividendIncome | number:2}}</td>
       <td align="right">{{dividendIncome.taxExempt| number:2}}</td>
    
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```